# Perl: check for files (-f vs. ! -d)

Tags: file, perl

I am a bit confused. I would expect -f to be equal to ! -d.

But it seems that is not the case. I try to check if a file is a directory or not.

```
use File::Find;
find (\&found, ".");

sub found ()
{
  my $fn = $File::Find::name;
  if( ! -d $fn)
  {
    print "\n1 " . $fn;         # a file
  }
  else
  {
    print "\n0 " . $fn;         # a directory
  }
}
```

Results for **! -d**
is what I would expect regarding my test-directory.

```
0 .
1 ./Whatever.mp3
1 ./x.pl
0 ./bb
1 ./bb/Whatever.mp3
0 ./aa
1 ./aa/Whatever.mp3
```

Results for **-f** are unexpected.

```
0 .
1 ./Whatever.mp3
1 ./x.pl
0 ./bb
0 ./bb/Whatever.mp3            # ???
0 ./aa
0 ./aa/Whatever.mp3            # ???
```

Comment: Are they symlinks? An `ls -alR` for reference here would help illustrate.

Comment: You are right. I added $fn at the very beginning of &found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `find` changes to the directory that contains the file before calling the callback.

This means that you are passing `./bb/Whatever.mp3` when you should be passing `Whatever.mp3`. As a result, both `-f` and `-d` are returning `undef` to signal an error occurred.

`$File::Find::name` contains the path to the file relative to the original CWD. On the other hand, `$_` contains the path to the file relative to the CWD. This is what you should be using.

```
use File::Find;

find({ wanted => \&found, no_chdir => 1 }, ".");

sub found {
   if (!stat($_)) {
      warn("Can't stat \"$_\": $!\n");
      return;
   }

   if (-d _)  {
      print "0 $_\n;   # A directory
   } else {
      print "1 $_\n";  # Some other kind of file
   }
}
```

I've included two other changes.

**Check for errors**

We could use

```
my $rv = -d $_;
if (!defined($rv)) {
   warn("Can't stat \"$_\": $!\n");
   return;
}

if ($rv)  {
   ...
}
```

But since the *`-X`* functions are simply wrappers for the `stat` system call, I find it a bit cleaner to use `stat` up front to check for errors, and use the special handle `_` thereon to avoid doing additional calls to `stat`. The special handle `_` tells `-d` to use the results of the previous call to `stat`/*`-X`*.

**Avoid needless calls to `chdir`**

Now that you're not using `$File::Find::name`, there's no point in having `find` call `chdir` all those times. This is what the `no_chdir => 1` does.

---

To answer the question you actually asked, there are two situations where `-f` isn't equal to `!-d`.

**Possibility 1**: You are unable to `stat` the file.

`-f` and `-d` return one of three different values:

- undefined: An error occurred.
- defined and false: It's not a plain file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`)
- defined and true: It's a plain file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`)

If the provided path doesn't exist, if you don't have permission to read the directory in which the file resides, or if some other error occurs, both `-f` and `!-d` will `undef` (and `$!` will contain the error code/message).

**Possibility 2**: The file is neither a plain file nor a directory.

Plain files (`-f`) and directories (`-d`) are just two of the seven types of files. The following are the others:

- Symbolic links (`-l`)
- Named pipes aka "fifos" (`-p`)
- Sockets (`-S`)
- Block devices (`-b`)
- Character devices (`-c`)

One and only one of these seven will be true.

---

Full file type check example:

```
stat($qfn)
   or die("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");

if    (-f _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a plain file."; }
elsif (-d _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a directory."; }
elsif (-l _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a symbolic link."; }
elsif (-p _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a named pipe."; }
elsif (-S _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a socket."; }
elsif (-b _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a block device."; }
elsif (-c _) { say "\"$qfn\" is a character device."; }
else         { say "\"$qfn\" is of unknown type."; }  # Shouldn't happen on unix systems.
```

Comment: Another option to avoid the initial issue is to pass `Cwd::cwd()` instead of `'.'` so that `$File::Find::name` will be an absolute path. Though `no_chdir` is a good option to pass in either case.

Comment: @Grinnz, No, the alternative to using `no_chdir` is using `$_` (path rel to CWD) instead of `$File::Find::name` (path relative to original CWD). In fact, one should always be using `$_` here. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are more types of files than regular files and directories, for example, device files (in the /dev/* hierarchy).

```
foreach (qw(/tmp/somefile /tmp/somedir /dev/sda)) {
    print "$_: ";
    print q(-f: true ) if -f;
    print q(-d: true ) if -d;
}
continue {
    print "\n";
}
```

If you run the code above, you'll notice that for `/dev/sda`, we have both `! -d`, and `! -f`, therefore `-f` is not equivalent to `! -d`.

See also: [perlfunc#-X](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Comment: It's very unlikely that `./bb/Whatever.mp3` is anything but a plain file.